# VS2008 Win32 console application debug version does not tell any memory leak

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char* pCh=new char[100];

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

My test code is very simple, it does has a memory leak? But why I press F5 to debug run, it does not tell me any memory leak?    But It did in some application before.   Why? about the settings or different project?   can any one help?   Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take [special steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28VS.71%29.aspx) to enable memory leak reporting - include special headers so that `malloc()` calls are replaced with [`malloc_dbg()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faz3a37z%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) calls and also call [`_CrtSetDbgFlag()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28VS.71%29.aspx) and pass `_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG` and `_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF` flags there so that leaks are reported when the program terminates.